# Tomcat SSL certificate from Windows cert manager

Tags: tomcat, config

I am trying to configure Tomcat 9 with a SSL certificate, I can do this successfully using a .pfx and by setting the server.xml with:

```
<Connector
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="C:\Temp\test.pfx" keystorePass="password"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

I would like to utilise an existing cert from Windows certificate manager, without the need for a password to be stored in plain text.

I would also prefer not to use the Java key-store, but if this is the only way to do it then I will have to.

Comment: Have you tried keystore type `Windows-MY`?

Answer (score 1):

Note there are multiple keystoreType for the windows connector configuration. I know of "Windows-MY" and "Windows-Root".

"Windows-MY" - Personal certificate store
"Windows-Root" - Trusted Root CA store

If you are running Tomcat as a service you will need to use Windows-Root or set the certificate into System accounts Personal certificate store.

Ensure your certificates are in the correct store by running "certmgr.msc".